# Optimal way for sending variable value from php to js script in Moodle

Tags: javascript, jquery, moodle

I've modal popup in my Moodle filter, but some variables should be defined in my php script and I can't set it right in JS. example "MyVariable":

```
define(['jquery', 'core/modal_factory'], function($, ModalFactory) {
  var trigger = $('#create-modal');
  ModalFactory.create({
    title: 'test title',
    body: '<p>test body content</p><a href="#" id="a-element">Click me</a>',
    footer: 'test footer content',
  }, trigger)
  .done(function(modal) {
    // Do what you want with your new modal.
    var MyVariable;  // I need to set this variable value from my php script
  });
});
```

Now I can use this way and add some html tags with variable value right in code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="5" id="get-variable" />
or
<div data-value="5" style="display:none" id="get-variable"></div>
```

and take the value by

```
$("#get-variable").val() or $("#get-variable").attr("data-value")
```

but maybe it is possible to send variable to my modal JS more correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send variables to the modal, just pass them in the create method, through the parameter "templateContext":

```
define(['jquery', 'core/modal_factory'], function($, ModalFactory) {
   var trigger = $('#create-modal');

   var myVariable

   ModalFactory.create({
      title: 'test title',
      body: '<p>test body content</p><a href="#" id="a-element">Click me</a>',
      footer: 'test footer content',
      templateContext : myVariable
   }, trigger)
   .done(function(modal) {
      // Do what you want with your modal
   });
});
```

If you're using mustache templates, and want to pass the variables after the modal has been mounted, you can use templates.render as a parameter of the setBody method (or setFooter, or setHead):

```
define(['jquery', 'core/modal_factory'], function($, ModalFactory) {
   var trigger = $('#create-modal');

   var myVariable

   ModalFactory.create({
      title: 'test title',
      body: '<p>test body content</p><a href="#" id="a-element">Click me</a>',
      footer: 'test footer content'
   }, trigger)
   .done(function(modal) {
      modal.setBody(templates.render('your_mustache_file', myVariable))
   });
});
```